# Локаторы в Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Написал метод, который находит элемент на странице. В качестве параметра я выбрал переменную типа `by`.

```
public Element(By XPath)
    {
        InformationAboutBrowser.GoToAttribute("waitTime");
        int waitTime =Convert.ToInt32(InformationAboutBrowser.GetAttribute("name"));
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(waitTime));
        WebElement = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(XPath));
    }
```

Если я хочу вызвать метод, то что мне передавать в качестве параметра? Что вообще есть переменная типа `by`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тип `By` - это класс, описывающий механизм нахождения элемента в некотором документе (в вашем случае, это html-страница).

Если проще, то переменная типа `By` - это локатор, который чаще всего используется методом драйвера `driver.FindElement`.

Приведу пример инициализации:

```
By submitButtonLocator = By.XPath("//input[@type='submit']");
```

В данном примере используется локатор типа `XPath`. Внутри скобок указывается строка, описывающая сам локатор.

Тип `By` выполняет функцию обобщения всех локаторов (своеобразный полиморфизм для локаторов). Т.е. переменная типа `By` может быть локатором любого типа.

Если вы хотите вызвать метод, то можете передать в качестве параметра `submitButtonLocator`, описанный выше, или любой другой локатор.

Comment: Ну вот допустим в данном примере я вызываю `Element element = new Element(By.XPath("//div[@id='genre_tab']"));` и ошибку на `By` выдаёт

Comment: какую ошибку выдает?

Comment: @ПавелКушнеревич и вообще, в вопросе у вас не метод, а конструктор.

Comment: в тесте не подключил Selenium, думал, что фреймворка хватит :)

Comment: спасибо большое)

Comment: @ПавелКушнеревич честно, я так и подумал, когда вы написали, что оно ругается на `By` :) Пожалуйста.